# Why $X$ independent from $(Y,Z)$ implies that $E(XY^{-1} | Z)= E(X) E(Y^{-1}|Z)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have three random variables. Let $X$ be independent from $(Y,Z)$ ($:=\sigma(Y,Z))$,
$Y\neq0$ a.s.

**Q: How can I proof (if it holds), that $E\left(\frac{X}{Y} \mid Z\right)=E(X) E\left(\frac{1}{Y}\mid Z\right)$ ?**

From answers to an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55524/rule-with-independent-random-variables-and-conditional-expectations) that this follows under the assumption X independent from $(\frac{1}{Y}, Z)$, however I would really like to avoid to have to assume this directly.

I know that there is a propositon that for $X_i\colon \Omega \to E_i$ independent, $\varphi_i\colon E_i \to E'_i$ measurable, $\varphi_i \circ X_i$ are independent as well, this used for $(X,Y,Z)$, (id, $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, id$)$,  I have $X,\frac{1}{Y}, Z$ independent, but this means that $\sigma(X), \sigma(\frac{1}{Y}), \sigma(Z)$ are independent, and not $\sigma(X), \sigma(\frac{1}{Y},Z)$. But maybe it can still be used?

Comment: That older question says $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $X$ is independent of $Z$, but stops short of saying $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$, which is a stronger condition.  But I suspect that that stronger condition may have been intended.  However, if $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$, then $X$ is independent of $(1/Y,Z)$, so you get the result you want.

Comment: So from @Didier's answer, it follows that $X$ and $(1/Y,Z)$ are independent if $X$ and $(Y,Z)$ are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property holds and indeed, it is a consequence of the fact that $X$ is independent on $(Y,Z)$ (which, by the way, is a synonym of the fact that $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y,Z)$ are independent sigma-algebras). To see this, let us first state a slightly more general result.

> **Lemma** Let $T$ denote any random variable and $u$ any measurable function. Then, $\sigma(u(T))\subseteq\sigma(T)$.

How does this apply to your setting? Take $T=(Y,Z)$ and $u:(y,z)\mapsto(1/y,z)$ and let $U=1/Y$. Then $u(T)=(U,Z)$. Since $u$ is one-to-one on $\mathbb R^*\times\mathbb R$, $u\circ u$ is one-to-one as well and the lemma applies to $u$ and to $u\circ u$. But $u\circ u$ is in fact the identity, hence $\sigma(Y,Z)\subseteq\sigma(U,Z)\subseteq\sigma(Y,Z)$, which proves that $\sigma(U,Z)=\sigma(Y,Z)$.

Finally, $X$ is independent on $\sigma(Y,Z)$ if and only if $X$ is independent on $\sigma(U,Z)$ and this fact is a tautology.

Now to the proof of the lemma. Assume the event $A$ is in $\sigma(u(T))$. As you know, this means there exists a measurable $B$ such that $A=[u(T)\in B]$. Recall that $u^{-1}(B)=\{t\mid u(t)\in B\}$ and let $C=u^{-1}(B)$. Then $C$ is measurable and $A=[T\in C]$, hence $A$ belongs to $\sigma(T)$ and the lemma holds.

---

**Edit** This is to answer the OP's comment below, without the length limitations associated to comments since it appears necessary to come back in details to some definitions.

Consider a set $\Omega$ and a function $\xi:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. To say that $\xi$ is a random variable is simply to add to this fact three conditions:

1. The source space $\Omega$ is endowed with a sigma-algebra, say $\mathcal F$.
2. The target space $\mathbb R$ is endowed with a sigma-algebra, usually the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal B$.
3. And $[\xi\in B]$ is an event for every $B$ in $\mathcal B$.

Recall that $[\xi\in B]$ is a notation for $\xi^{-1}(B)$ and that *to be an event* is probabilistic jargon for *to belong to $\mathcal F$* (once the sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ has been fixed).

Likewise, for any function $\Xi:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ with $n\geqslant1$, to ask that $\Xi$ is a (vector-valued) random variable would be to ask that $[\Xi\in B]$ is in $\mathcal F$, for every $B$ in the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal B_n$ on $\mathbb R^n$.

Right. It happens that every function $\xi:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ (random variable or not) defines a sigma-algebra $\sigma(\xi)$ on the source space $\Omega$, which is the collection of the subsets $[\xi\in B]$ for $B$ in $\mathcal B$. Yes, this is a sigma-algebra, always. Hence, to ask that $\xi$ is a random variable is to ask that 
$$
\sigma(\xi)\subseteq\mathcal F.
$$
Likewise, for  $\Xi:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ with $n\geqslant1$, to ask that $\Xi$ is a (vector-valued) random variable is to ask that $\sigma(\Xi)\subseteq\mathcal F$, where $\sigma(\Xi)$ is the collection of the subsets $[\Xi\in B]$ for $B$ in $\mathcal B_n$.

Rrrright. Now to your comment.

You consider two random variables $Y$ and $Z$ and the function $T=(Y,Z)$ defined, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$, by $T(\omega)=(Y(\omega),Z(\omega))$. First note that, since you assumed that $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables, this is enough to guarantee that $T$ is a (vector-valued) random variable. Why? Well, to check directly that $[T\in B]$ is in $\mathcal F$ for every $B$ in $\mathcal B_2$ might not be easy but there is a two-steps way to do so, that is both classical and easy:

1. Check this for products $B=B_1\times B_2$ with $B_1$ and $B_2$ in $\mathcal B$. To do so, simply write $[T\in B_1\times B_2]$ as $[Y\in B_1]\cap[Z\in B_2]$ and use the definitions.
2. Consider the collection of events $\mathcal C=\{B\in\mathcal B_2\mid [T\in B]\in\mathcal F\}$. You just proved that $\mathcal B\times\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal C$ and you know by definition that $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal B_2$. Since the sigma-algebra $\mathcal B_2$ is generated by $\mathcal B\times\mathcal B$, you know that $\sigma(\mathcal C)=\mathcal B_2$. But since $\mathcal C$ is a sigma-algebra (yes, always), $\mathcal C=\sigma(\mathcal C)$.
   Hence $\mathcal C=\mathcal B_2$, which is a rewriting of the result you wanted to prove.

Thus, $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables and $T=(Y,Z)$ is a (vector-valued) random variable and you know the definitions of $\sigma(Y)$, $\sigma(Z)$ and $\sigma(T)$, which are all sub-sigma-algebras of $\mathcal F$.

Well, it seems you are ready for the *Grand final*:

> Let $\mathcal G=\sigma(\sigma(Y)\cup\sigma(Z))$. Then $\mathcal G=\sigma(T)$ $(\ast)$.

In other words, the two meanings of $\sigma(Y,Z)$ one can think about are in fact equivalent! We happy.

Recall one last time that $\mathcal G=\sigma(Y^{-1}(\mathcal B)\cup Z^{-1}(\mathcal B))$ and $\sigma(T)=\sigma(T^{-1}(\mathcal B_2))$ and that these are two sigma-algebras on $\Omega$.

To prove $(\ast)$, note that $[Y\in B]=[T\in B\times\mathbb R]$ and likewise for $Z$, hence $\sigma(Y)\cup\sigma(Z)\subseteq\sigma(T)$ hence  $\mathcal G\subseteq\sigma(T)$. For the other inclusion, use once again the idea explained above and consider 
$$
\mathcal D=\{B\in\mathcal B_2\mid [T\in B]\in\mathcal G\}.
$$
By definition, $\mathcal D\subseteq\mathcal B_2$ and almost by definition, $\mathcal B\times\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal D$, hence you can probably finish this yourself.

Comment: What is confusing me: On the one hand, $(Y,Z):=\sigma(Y,Z)$($=\sigma(X^{-1}(\mathcal{F}) \cup Y^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))$) ($(\Omega, \mathcal{P}, \mathbb{P})$ is our probability space) is then generated $\sigma$-algebra, on the other hand with random variable $T:=(Y,Z)$ we use $(Y,Z)$ for the vector of the two random variables $Y$ and $Z$

Comment: @Johannes, the *Edit* addresses your question. Please tell me if anything is unclear.

Comment: Very nice answer. I could follow your argument, except that I still have to think a little to make it clear to myself that $\mathcal{D}$ (resp. $\mathcal{C}$) is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra. Maybe it's worth to put it as a single question/answer pair so I can award you an "accepted answer" for the question why $\sigma(X,Y)$ ( $(X,Y)$ random vector) $=\sigma(X,Y)$ ($(X,Y)$ as the generated \sigma-algebra)

Comment: Re D and C being sigma-algebras: yes, this is the heart of the proofs. Just take the axioms that make a sigma-algebra one at a time and there should be no problem checking them.